# Caminho relativo para txt em ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp

Boa tarde, estou gerando um arquivo com Asp net a função salva no HD se eu colocar o caminho, porém esse arquivo será salvo em um servidor e estou com dificuldade pra  colocar o caminho relativo do local onde este arquivo vai ser salvo, não sei se estou usando a função correta pois sou novato.

função que estou usando:

```
 string[] lines = {ENAME, FNAME,LNAME };
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"~/WriteLines.csv", lines);
```

erro gerado:

> Detalhes da ExceÃ§Ã£o: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Não foi possível localizar uma parte do caminho 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\~\WriteLines.csv'.

Comment: Talvez te ajude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268738/asp-net-mvc-find-absolute-path-to-the-app-data-folder-from-controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para obter o caminho relativo, você pode utilizar esta forma:

```
 string[] lines = {ENAME, FNAME,LNAME };
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(Server.MapPath("~/WriteLines.csv"), lines);
```

Assim, basta concatenar com o seu código.

O código Server.MapPath mapeia para o diretório físico correspondente.

Comment: Deu certo, muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a função `Server.MapPath("~/WriteLines.csv")`. Ficaria assim:

```
string[] lines = {ENAME, FNAME,LNAME };
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(Server.MapPath("~/WriteLines.csv"), lines);
```